# Why does Eimu wear a different uniform?

Tags: ayakashi

When Eimu joins the class, she has a different uniform from everyone else, which I figured was acceptable because she was coming from a different school.

However, she stays in the school for quite a bit of time (and we see that she even owns the uniform in episode 5 or so). Why then does she continue to wear the blue uniform the entire way through the show?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Marika didn't wear same uniform with others?](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/12935/why-marika-didnt-wear-same-uniform-with-others)

Comment: Wut? Both are different series...

Comment: The answer is pretty much the same, so I voted to close it as "This question may already have an answer here:"

Comment: The problem is that duplicated means: "**This question** has been asked before and already has an answer." That the same answer applies to different questions doesn't mean in any way they are duplicated, unless you make this (or the other) question *more general*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much like [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/12935/why-marika-didnt-wear-same-uniform-with-others), this is most likely to be part of the *Transfer Student Uniform* trope that features in a few anime.

[TVTropes page](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TransferStudentUniforms)

> New Transfer Students in places where school uniforms are a cultural default setting often wear their old ones until the school can provide them with a new one. In fiction, this shows the newcomer or outsider. When they get the current school uniform, this indicates they've been assimilated. If the student is meant to be a Fish out of Water, they will keep their old uniform throughout the series. In Japanese media, even rebels don't choose to abandon uniforms entirely; in American media they will do this even if the new school doesn't have uniforms. Compare the Non-Uniform Uniform.

Thanks to @Jon_Lin