# Why doesn't Marika wear same uniform as the others?

Tags: nisekoi

Despite being a transfer student, Marika should have been given a uniform. But why didn't they give her one? Chitoge wpre the same uniform since her first day.

[image][image]

In manga chapter 129 (Now it has 131 chapters)

[image]

Comment: Don't really recall that specifically, was that on her transfer day or every day? I guess her uniform didn't arrive if the later?

Comment: @Prix the one in class room is from episode 18... I don't really pay attention in manga because, well, it's black and white, I added the source from manga

Comment: Well I never read the manga for this. I was talking about the anime was not that ep the one she transferred into the school?

Comment: every day I guess? even on latest chapter she still wear that uniform, it means that she didn't have same uniform with others

Comment: @Prix FYI, the day she transfer, she didn't wear any uniform, she wear casual dress, it's in episode 14

Comment: Well spotted, I can only think that due to the fact she transferred at mid terms or so, her uniform was not yet ready for delivery and at that point the anime was pretty fast towards the end. Most likely the manga tells why she uses the same uniform, **I don't recall that information being said on the anime.**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this case, Marika is probably wearing her old school's uniform. As a transfer student, there's a grace period before you get provided the one the school designates (they are typically purchased).

This is also the case of the [Transfer Student Uniforms](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TransferStudentUniforms) trope:

> New Transfer Students in places where school uniforms are a cultural default setting often wear their old ones until the school can provide them with a new one. **In fiction, this shows the newcomer or outsider. When they get the current school uniform, this indicates they've been assimilated**. If the student is meant to be a Fish out of Water, they will keep their old uniform throughout the series. In Japanese media, even rebels don't choose to abandon uniforms entirely; in American media they will do this even if the new school doesn't have uniforms. Compare the Non-Uniform Uniform.

Answer (score 6):

Aside from the "assimilation" thing, it's worth mentioning that school uniforms normally aren't just stored in bulk somewhere in the school's designated warehouse of uniforms. That'd be ridiculous because all students have different measurements. Can you imagine the amount of unused uniforms of all shapes and sizes?

Each student orders their uniform before the year begins, and they all get it on time. Students that transfer in the middle of the year have to order their uniform separately from all other students, and may even have to wait until the required materials are shipped to the factory. So there's really nothing unusual going on, just everyday life stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Myabe she doesn't want to? Not that I know this for a fact within the story, but remembering Nagi No Asu Kara, the characters had agreed to keep wearing their old school uniforms on purpose as a way of saying they didn't belong to the new school.

Comment: Nagi-asu also shows how hard is to get a new uniform mid-term, in the second season Hikari has to travel to town and order a uniform from a tailor.

Comment: `Myabe she doesn't want to? Not that I know this for a fact within the story` Did she ever say that she doesn't want to wear the new school uniform? Since you are citing the character's preference rather than the circumstances, I think some reference from the series itself is in order.

Comment: Thanks, and you are right, if the others had their uniforms ready it may have been because the exchange was arranged way ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

It's true that if she transferred in the middle of the year she would have had do wait...but she transferred in their first year and the manga is already like halfway through second year (even the anime is into the second year) so at this point if she is still not wearing it it's cause she doesn't want to... Realistically, she would have been written up by this point by a disciplinary person but because this is an anime/manga it's probably the whole "character look" thing. Even if this were real life, she clearly has a lot of power and authority due to her father's position so maybe they'd get the school to look the other way, be it she just wants to stand out or she's more comfortable with her old clothes. Marika is a more modest, feminine person so could you really picture her in a mini skirt?